# How can a user grant/deny permission to receive Notifcations via a Toggle?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to implement Notifications into a Swift project. I have created a very basic project to do this. At the moment I have got it asking the user for permission to receive notifications after the app is launched. This has been achieved by doing the following:

Adding this code:

```
import SwiftUI
import UserNotifications

@main
struct TestingNotificationsApp: App {
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) { granted, error in
            if granted {
                print("Notification permission granted")
            } else if let error = error {
                print("Error requesting notification permission: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
        
        return true
    }
}
```

And adding the following permissions in my Info.plist

```
<key>NSLocalNotificationsUsageDescription</key>
<string>Notification permission is required to send you important updates.</string>
<key>NSRemoteNotificationsUsageDescription</key>
<string>Notification permission is required to send you important updates.</string>
```

Here is the rest of my code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        Home()
    }
}
```

```
import SwiftUI

struct Home: View {
        
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
            
            Text("Hello, world!")
                .padding()
            
            //Insert Toggle Here:
                
        }
    }
}
```

In the Home() view I want to add a toggle that the user can use to allow/deny notification permissions.

If permissions are granted (taking into account permissions being enabled / disabled in the device Settings app), the toggle should be on and the app should allow notifications.

If permissions are not granted, the toggle should be off and if the toggle is tapped, permissions to receive notifications should be granted.

Also how would be the best way to integrate a local notification? Would something like this in the App file be effective?

```
let isNotificationsEnabled = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isNotificationsEnabled")
        if isNotificationsEnabled {
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) { granted, error in
                if granted {
                    print("Notifications permission granted.")
                    testNotification1()
                } else {
                    print("Notifications permission denied because: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "unknown error").")
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: The application notification settings are in the Notification Center. This is a global convention, why do you want to change it?

Comment: This is not possible: once user denied permissions, they can only enable them via the settings.

Answer (score -1):

If the user denies the notification permission request, the only way for your app to gain that permission is by manually enabling them via system settings.

A common practice is to present an alert to the user informing them of missing notification permissions and then opening the settings app for them.